# About types of grading of associative algebras

Tags: abstract-algebra, terminology, graded-rings

There is a known result says that for $G$ as a finite group. If $A$ be an (assocatively) $G$-graded associative algebra such that the homogeneous component $A_1$ satisfies a polynomial identity of degree $d$, then the entire algebra $A$ satisfies a polynomial identity with degree bounded above by an explicit function of $d$ and $|G|$.
My question is about what is the meaning of

> associatively $G$-graded

in this context?

Comment: Just that $A=\oplus_{g\in G} A_g$ with $A_gA_h\subseteq A_{gh}$ for all $h,g\in A$ and the product is associative.

Comment: Should be "for all $h,g\in G$" in Dietrichs comment.

Comment: For example $A = k[T]/(T^n-1)$ with $G = \Bbb{Z/nZ}$ and $A_g = k T^g$